# Beginner Java Logical Error: Not sure I know what to do for this algorithm

Tags: java

I have an encrypting algorithm to use for practice, but I'm not sure I'm coding it right. It is in the encrypt method that I am having trouble.

My algorithm is as follows (and I quote):
"Replace each digit by the remainder after (the sum of that digit plus 7) is divided by 10."

EDIT: 1234 should become 8901

What do I do? Am I on the right track at all?

```
import java.util.*;
    public class encrypt 
    {
      public static void main(String[] args)
      {
        int num;
        num = getnum();
        encrypt(num);
      }
      public static int getnum()
      {
        Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
        int num;
        do
        {
        System.out.println("Enter a number that has only four digits ");
        num = console.nextInt(); 
        }
        while (num < 1000 || num > 9999);
        return num;
      }
      public static int encrypt(int num)
      {
        int digit4 = num%10;
        num = num/10;
        int digit3 = num%10;
        num = num/10;
        int digit2 = num%10;
        num = num/10;
        int digit1 = num%10;
        num = num/10;
        digit4 = ((digit4 + 7)/10)%10;
        digit3 = ((digit3 + 7)/10);
        digit2 = ((digit2 + 7)/10);
        digit1 = ((digit1 + 7)/10);
        System.out.print(digit1+" "+digit2+" "+digit3+" "+digit4);
        return digit4;
      }
    }
```

Comment: any sample output?? that you want to achive?

Comment: `Am I on the right track at all?` Go, run it and check it out yourself.

Comment: I just ran this code successfully.. No Errors buddy. Just check

Comment: Sorry, I put sample output in. It doesn't work logically speaking.

Comment: you can use for loops or recursive methods to remove some duplicated code...

Comment: I could but I'm just trying to fix the logical errors at the moment, that I will do later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In all cases digit+7 is between 7 and 16, so to get the remainder, just subtract 10 if the digit is 10 or more, i.e.

```
if (digit4 >= 10) digit4 -= 10;
if (digit3 >= 10) digit3 -= 10;
if (digit2 >= 10) digit2 -= 10;
if (digit1 >= 10) digit1 -= 10;
```

You'll want to return

```
digit1 * 1000 + digit2 * 100 + digit3 * 10 + digit4
```

rather than just digit4.  Beyond that, use a for loop to improve so that it'll work for numbers bigger than 9999.

Comment: Yeah I knew about the return just threw something in there to prevent a compiler error, thanks.